# Suggested tags for new questions via neural networks

Tags: feature-request, suggested-tags

Google built an automatic tagging engine (currently limited to one tag per post): https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/10/intro-to-text-classification-with-keras-automatically-tagging-stack-overflow-posts

This sounds like a nice feature to suggests tags for a new question.

(I was [asked on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/921071069674455040) to add this here.)

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm missing information on their setup. Neural networks can be computationally intensive, and there are a lot of people asking questions on Stack Overflow. I also doubt if it's any useful information, because it only adds one tag per question. For anyone posting an SQL question the neural net can guess the [tag:sql] tag, but further tags are also needed, and only suggesting one can lead to people just going with that. Also, those first tags are usually the easiest for the user to enter.

Comment: Yes, it probably needs to be advanced to make it useable.

Comment: We have a feature that automatically suggests tags. I'm not sure what the implementation is, but unless there's evidence it is not working well, I'm not sure what the advantage would be to switching to something different.

Comment: It would be interesting to test on egsisting tags.